# Byte string deserialization taking into account zero values ​in the fields

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

I collect the message according to my protofile (listed below). Then I serialize it into a byte string using SerializeToString() method. Then i get the byte string message and deserialization into proto object using ParseFromString() method.
But if i fill in the some fields zero values and execute the above algorithm like this:

```
def test():
    fdm = device_pb2.FromDeviceMessage()
    fdm.deveui = bytes.fromhex('1122334455667788')
    fdm.fcntup = 0
    fdm.battery = 3.5999999046325684
    fdm.mode = 0
    fdm.event = 1
    port = fdm.data.add()
    port.port = 1 #device_pb2.PortData.Name(0)
    port.value = 0
    c = fdm.SerializeToString()
    return c

def parse_test(data):
    print(data)
    res = device_pb2.FromDeviceMessage()
    res.ParseFromString(data)
    return res

print(parse_test(test()))
```

, then python console will show me:

```
deveui: "\021\"3DUfw\210"
battery: 3.5999999046325684
event: PERIOD_EVENT
data {
  port: VIBR2
}
```

without fields values are zero.

But i want to see:

```
deveui: "\021\"3DUfw\210"
fcntup: 0
battery: 3.5999999046325684
mode: BOUNDARY
event: PERIOD_EVENT
data {
  port: VIBR2
  value: 0
}
```

Why is it happening, and if it's fixed how can i fix it?

=============Proto_File================

```
message FromDeviceMessage{
    bytes deveui = 1; 
    uint32 ts = 2; 
    int32 fcntup = 3; 
    float battery = 4;
    int32 period = 5; 
    Mode mode = 6; 
    Event event = 7; 
    repeated PortData data = 8; 
}

message PortData{
    DevicePort port = 1;
    int32 value = 2;
}

enum Mode{
    BOUNDARY = 0;
    PERIOD = 1;
    BOUNDARY_PERIOD = 2;
}

enum Event{
    BOUNDARY_EVENT = 0;
    PERIOD_EVENT = 1;
}

enum DevicePort{
    VIBR1  = 0;
    VIBR2  = 1;
    TEMPL2 = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i think i guessed the reason. In case `enum type` ( DevicePort, Event, Mode): the default value is the first defined enum value, which must be 0. So i will set up 1 value to see required fields. In other cases: the fields with zero values are not displayed to reduce memory size of package. But if i turn to the required field using this way: `res.data[0].value` (in `def parse_test(data)`) it will show me `0`, if i set value `0` in field `value`, for example. And this rule works in all cases.